# AutoCompleteTextView, como fazer pesquisa em qualquer ponto da sentença?

Tags: android

Galera,

Tenho um AutoCompleteTextView e preciso que ele faça o filtro não apenas pelo início da sentença mas de qualquer parte dela.

ex> minha lista: *KMF Avaré, Florisio (KMF Sorocaba)*

Quando digito a letra "K" ele traz apenas o *KMF Avaré*, mas preciso que traga também o *Florisio KMF Sorocaba*.

É possível fazer a pesquisa/filtro a partir de qualquer ponto da sentença?

Comment: Depende de como estás a fazer o filtro. Mostra algum código de como tens feito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Fiz o seguinte:

Criei um BaseAdapter implementando Filterable e nela fiz a lógica do filtro:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {          
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            listaAdapter = new ArrayList<String>();

            if (constraint != null) {

                for (String item : listaCompleta) {                     
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        listaAdapter.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            else listaAdapter = listaCompleta;

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = listaAdapter;
            results.count = listaAdapter.size();

            return results;
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
```